# can i define more than one public class in a java package

Tags: java, class, package, public

i want to create a java package containing some classes .But non public classes cannot be accessed from outside a package so i write this code a saved it as Box.java

```
package mypack;
public class Box
{
int length,breadth,height;
public Box(int l,int b,int h)
    {
    length=l;
    breadth=b;
    height=h;
    }
public  int vol()
    {
    return length*breadth*height;
    }
} 

public class circle
{
 int r;
 public circle(int rr)
    {
    r=rr;
    }
 public float area()
    {
    return (3.14f*r*r);
    }
 }
```

is it possible to create a package like this . if possible what file name should i give it 'Box.java' or 'circle.java'

Comment: In a package, yes, just not in one (.java) file. It should be Box.java AND Circle.java

Comment: There are simple rules: 1) Only one `public` class can be defined in one `.java` file. But many `.java` file can exists in a package. A package is a directory in file system. 2) The `.java` file should named as the **exact** name of the **public class** which is defined inside it. 3) More than one class can be defined in a `.java` file, but only one of them can be `public`.

Answer (score 5):

There can be more than one `public` class in package, but each public class needs to be declared in its own `.java` file. If you want these `public` classes that are in different `.java` files to be contained in the same package, simply put `package mypack;` at the very beginning of these `.java` files. This is the example, how you should name these files:

1. `Box.java`:

   ```
    package mypack;
    public class Box {...}
   ```
2. `Circle.java`:

   ```
    package mypack;
    public class Circle {...}
   ```

Note that files should be named with name of `public` class contained in it (if `public` class is present inside).

*By the way, be aware of naming conventions in Java language - it might save your and others time when looking at code - class names should start with capital letter, so in your case it should be `Circle` class and `Circle.java`, not `circle` class and `circle.java`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can only create only one `public` type (like a class/interface, etc..) inside a source file as explained below from Java documentation (emphasis is mine).

> To create a package, you choose a name for the package (naming
>   conventions are discussed in the next section) and put a package
>   statement with that name at the top of every source file that contains
>   the types (classes, interfaces, enumerations, and annotation types)
>   that you want to include in the package.
>   **If you put multiple types in a single source file, only one can be
>   public, and it must have the same name as the source file**.

I suggest you read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html) on how to create and manage packages and source/class files in java.

Also, note that you are allowed to contain **more than one non-public (default access)** types inside a single source file as shown below:

**Inside your Circle.java File:**

```
package mypack;

class Box { //non-public (default) class
 //code for Box class
} 

public class Circle {//public class
  //code for circle class
}
```

Also, inside a package, you can create any number of `public` classes (by following above rule). But, as a good practice, group your classes properly into various packages according to their relevance.